# CSS beginner, need help positioning overlapped DIV

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to create a section where it splits into 2 sections with a small square in the middle of the section. I'm having a trouble with the positioning, I managed to put the black box in the middle but it won't overlap the blue section.

```css
.attachment {
  cursor: default;
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 93px;
  height: 93px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: -43px;
  margin-top: -47px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
  </div>
  <div class="attachment"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46aoyrjc/

Comment: Remove in the class .`split`-  `overflow-x: hidden;` and add to the class `.right` - `z-index:1` - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/gxcfeb51/3/

Comment: You have to remove the `overflow:hidden` from the split divs and remove `z-index:1` from the left div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't overlap the blue one because of the `overflow-x: hidden;` in `.split` if you remove it it's going to overlap it.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to say to add `z-index: 2;` to `.right`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative margin to do this.

```css
#blue{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#red{
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

#black{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
</div>

<div id="red">
<div id="black">
</div>
</div>
```